# Symfony 4 and PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, symfony, phpspreadsheet

Currently I try to use this PHP Spreadsheet Bundle for Symfony 4:
https://github.com/roromix/SpreadsheetBundle

But my attempts to use this bundle are not successful.
Can't find it as a service (php bin/console debug:autowiring)
and the way below is also wrong.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Roromix\Bundle\SpreadsheetBundle\RoromixSpreadsheetBundle;

class TranslationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $RoromixSpreadsheetBundle = new RoromixSpreadsheetBundle();

    //...
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for get service in your controller :

```
dump($this->get('phpspreadsheet'));
```

Because service name as `phpspreadsheet` : https://github.com/roromix/SpreadsheetBundle/blob/master/src/Resources/config/services.yml

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Because in most cases, SF4 does not allow controllers to pull these sorts of services from the container.

Comment: I didn't test it, I just read the code :)

`RoromixSpreadsheetBundle`are not a service in your bundle.

Comment: You're extends of `Controller`, you can use public service without inject  :)